# Using CocoaPods with frameworks and static libraries at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, static-libraries, cocoapods

I have this **Podfile** in my project:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'FunnyApp' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'VaultKit', :path => './Frameworks/VaultKit'
  pod 'SessionKit', :path => './Frameworks/SessionKit'
end
```

Only **VaultKit** is static library written in Objective-C. It has this podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'VaultKit'
  s.version = '0.1'
  s.license = 'MIT'
  s.summary = 'Encryption library'
  s.homepage = 'https://someurl.com'
  s.social_media_url = 'http://twitter.com/greenfish29'
  s.authors = { 'Tomas Sliz' => 'greenfish29@email.com' }
  s.source = { :git => 'git@github.org:greenfish29/vaultkit.git' }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.public_header_files = 'VaultKit/VaultKit.h'
  s.source_files = "VaultKit/*.{h,m}" "VaultKit/Models/*.{h,m}"

  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

I have bridging header in my project too with this record:

```
#import <VaultKit/VaultKit.h>
```

But when I try to build project, I get this error:

> FunnyApp-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: 'VaultKit.h' file not found

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods doesn't support both Frameworks and Static libraries and neither they have an intention to do so.

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3839).

I ended up using Obj-C only libraries for my project by using the bridging header because an important library which I couldn't do without had only an Obj-C version.

I think we may at least get support for dynamic frameworks which use static libraries as dependency in the future.